# Variable from a Class to a Dictionaries keys and values in to Function in Python

Tags: python, function, class

I am not a programmer and very new to programming. Trying to learn and understand python its way of working with classes , functions and variables.

I created this code below.

```
class Test:
    number = 1
    field = ['Address', 'Name', 'Age']

    def book(self):
        myDict = self.book
        myDict = {number : field}
        # Need my Output to be myDict = {1 : ['Address', 'Name', 'Age']}
        return myDict
```

It doesn't show any error while compiling but throws while calling the instance of that object

```
>>> te = Test()
>>> te.book()

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    te.book()
    myDict = {number : field}
NameError: name 'number' is not defined
```

What I have in my mind is that, the **variable** declared outside the function will be **global** and will be called in to the function if that variable is not available inside the function, can somebody please clarify me where I am going wrong understanding this concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`number` is declared outside of the method, not globally. It is a property of the class you created, so you should reference it as `self.number` or `Test.number`.

Answer (score 2):

not global variable, class variable, you can access them inside a function with the class name:

`myDict = {Test. number : Test.field}`